# Unsigned Bytes in Java

Tags: java, byte

Bytes in Java are signed by default. I see on other posts that a workaround to have unsigned bytes is something similar to that: `int num = (int) bite & 0xFF`

Could someone please explain to me why this works and converts a signed byte to an unsigned byte and then its respective integer? `ANDing` a byte with 11111111 results in the same byte - right?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

A typecast has a higher precedence than the `&` operator. Therefore you're first casting to an int, then ANDing in order to mask out all the high-order bits that are set, including the "sign bit" of the two's complement notation which java uses, leaving you with just the positive value of the original byte. E.g.:

```
let byte x = 11111111 = -1
then (int) x = 11111111 11111111 11111111 11111111
and x & 0xFF = 00000000 00000000 00000000 11111111 = 255
```

and you've effectively removed the sign from the original byte.

Comment: Hmm.. but I still get `239` if I forcibly do the `&` before the cast:  `System.out.println((int) (((byte) -17) & 0xFF));`

Comment: The typecast is actually unnecessary here because 0xFF is an integer literal (there are no byte literals).

Comment: So `11111111` unsigned is 255. However, as signed it is -1. Effectively what your code did was interpret it as unsigned instead of signed (which is default to Java)?

Comment: @Nayefc: yes, by changing to an int but keeping the exact same bit pattern, we can essentially represent an unsigned byte using a signed int. It still uses as much storage space as an int, though.

Comment: @aioobe: As Michael pointed out, 0xFF is an int and thus your byte gets promoted to an int, and the outcome is the same. After that, the two's complement of -17 is the same as 238 with the sign bit flipped (in 9 or more bits, anyway).

Comment: @RyanStewart to save storage space on that you might consider using a short rather than an int I guess

Answer (score 16):

> ANDing a byte with 11111111 results in the same byte - right?

Except you're ANDing with 00000000000000000000000011111111, because 0xFF is an `int` literal - there are no `byte` literals in Java. So what happens is that the `byte` is promoted to `int` (the typecast is unnecessary), has its sign extended (i.e. keeps the possibly negative value of the `byte`, but then the sign extension is reverted by ANDing it with all those zeroes. The result is an `int` that has as its least significant bits exactly the former `byte` and thus the value the `byte` would have had were it unsigned.

Comment: +1, you nailed it... As I understand it, the `& 0xFF` throws away the "sign-extended" ones. May be worth mentioning...

Answer (score 12):

In Java 8 such method appeared in Byte class:

```
/**
 * Converts the argument to an {@code int} by an unsigned
 * conversion.  In an unsigned conversion to an {@code int}, the
 * high-order 24 bits of the {@code int} are zero and the
 * low-order 8 bits are equal to the bits of the {@code byte} argument.
 *
 * Consequently, zero and positive {@code byte} values are mapped
 * to a numerically equal {@code int} value and negative {@code
 * byte} values are mapped to an {@code int} value equal to the
 * input plus 2<sup>8</sup>.
 *
 * @param  x the value to convert to an unsigned {@code int}
 * @return the argument converted to {@code int} by an unsigned
 *         conversion
 * @since 1.8
 */
public static int toUnsignedInt(byte x) {
    return ((int) x) & 0xff;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @gebuh the first paragraph of the JavaDoc answers the question, however not as explicitly (with actual binary numbers) as the accepted answer.

Comment: Yeah this does actually answer the question, it's just a little hard to understand why.

Answer (score 3):

As you see the result is an `int` not a byte

How it works, say we have a `byte b = -128;`, this is represented as `1000 0000`, so what happens when you execute your line? Let's use a temp int for this, say:
`int i1 = (int)b;` i1 is now -128 and this is actually represented in binary like this:

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0000
```

So what does `i1 & 0xFF` look like in binary?

```
1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1111 1000 0000
&
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111
```

which results in

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1000 0000
```

and this is exactly 128, meaning your signed value converted to unsigned.

**Edit**
Convertint byte `-128 .. 127` into `0 .. 255`

```
int unsignedByte = 128 + yourByte;
```

You cannot represent the values 128 to 255 by using a byte, you must use something else, like an int or a smallint.

Comment: Oh right! Got it.. So how would one convert a signed byte into an unsigned byte? So I am storing bytes, in Java they are interpreted as signed. How would I get the unsigned value of that byte? I need my byte to represent 0-255 instead of -128 -> +127

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but this way you can be sure you will never get a number >255 or <0.

If the first bit is 1, the number is negative. If you convert byte to int, if it is negative it will be pre-pended with 1 bytes and if positive, with 0 bytes. Running the and routine will drop all the bytes left of the first 8. This in effect adds 256 to negative bytes.